# Math.random функция javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function balanceUP(){
var bet = $('#bet').val();
var rand = Math.random(0,7);
if (rand <= 3) {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "details.php",
      data: {fbet:bet}
  })
} else {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "details2.php",
      data: {fbet:bet}
})
}
```

}
При нажатии на кнопку исполняется функция balanceUP
Почему то на сайте, при нажатии постоянно срабатывает условие в случае которого сгенерированное число <=3, а иначе вообще не работает, может я не правильно прописал Math.random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> может я не правильно прописал Math.random

Точно!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

```
// целое число от нуля то шести - включая границы
var rand = Math.floor(7 * Math.random());
```

Answer (score 1):

Пробуйте так:

```
// Возвращает случайное число между min 
//  (включительно) и max (не включая max)
function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```